# Проверить является ли домен русскоязычным

Tags: python

Есть ли пакеты и алгоритмы на Python, с помощью которых можно из массива доменных имён выбрать русскоязычные?

Исходные данные: около 200 тысяч доменов в сутки в разных доменных зонах.
Что хочу: определить какие домены были созданы соотечественниками, но в зонах com, site, cf и иже с ними.
Путь (один из): проверка домена на «русскоязычность»

У меня проблема с транслит-фразами, не разделёнными дефисами. Например:
tritopolya
luchsheekafe

Популярные модули детекта языка тут скорее всего не сработают, но это не точно.

Comment: По-моему задача сама по себе в принципе слишком размытая и невнятная

Comment: По-моему, у всех русскоязычных пользователей проблема с транслит-фразами. Особенно у тех, кто не слушал маму и не учил английский. Поэтому приготовьтесь наблюдать plag = пляж, devytka = девятка, konstitucii - конституции. У меня есть глубокое подозрение, что игра в принципе не стоит свеч. Разве что, определяйте контрагента по полю org, например, и выясняйте, чьим резидентом он является.